# Magento 2 how to change customers group based on order status with cron jobs

Tags: orders, cron, magento-2.1.7, crontab

If customer order status is pending and more than 30 days, how to change customer group to wholesale in CRONs?

CRONs should run at every one minute.

This is my code

```
public function execute()
{
     $today          = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
     $to             = strtotime('-02 min', strtotime($today));
     $to             = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $to);

    $filterGroupDate      = $this->filterGroup;
    $filterGroupStatus    = clone($filterGroupDate);

     $filterDate      = $this->filterBuilder
         ->setField('updated_at')
         ->setConditionType('to')
         ->setValue($to)
         ->create();
    $filterStatus    = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setField('status')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->setValue('pending_payment')
        ->create();

    $filterGroupDate->setFilters([$filterDate]);
    $filterGroupStatus->setFilters([$filterStatus]);

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups(
        [$filterGroupStatus]
    );
    $searchResults  = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria->create());


    $selectedgroup=3;



    /** @var Order $order */
    foreach ($searchResults->getItems() as $order) {
        $this->orderManagement->cancel($order->getId());
         $customer = $order->getCustomer();
         $customer->setData('customer_group_id', $selectedgroup)->save();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My suggestion to load customer from  order using customer repository**

```
$customer= $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById( $order->getCustomerId());
$customer->setGroupId($selectedgroup);
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

**Use above instead of below:**

```
 $customer = $order->getCustomer();
$customer->setData('customer_group_id', $selectedgroup)->save();
```

Also `customer_group_id` is wrong ,it should be `group_id`.where `customer_group_id` a field of order table where Magento save customer group during order placed.

Comment: Can you please elobrate it be helpfull....Amit Bera